# How to get all combinations from a given dictionary?

Tags: python, python-itertools

How to get all combinations (listed) from a given dictionary, in python ?

My input:

```
my_dict = {"location_01":"Item_01", "location_02":"Item_02", "location_03":"Item_03"}
```

Desidered output:

```
[{"location_01": "Item_01", "location_02": "Item_02", "location_03": "Item_03"},
 {"location_01": "Item_02", "location_02": "Item_01", "location_03": "Item_03"},
 {"location_01": "Item_03", "location_02": "Item_02", "location_03": "Item_01"},
 {"location_02": "Item_01", "location_01": "Item_02", "location_03": "Item_03"},
 {"location_02": "Item_02", "location_01": "Item_01", "location_03": "Item_03"},
 {"location_02": "Item_03", "location_01": "Item_02", "location_03": "Item_01"},
 {"location_03": "Item_01", "location_02": "Item_02", "location_01": "Item_03"},
 {"location_03": "Item_02", "location_02": "Item_01", "location_01": "Item_02"},
 {"location_03": "Item_03", "location_02": "Item_02", "location_01": "Item_01"}]
```

Comment: What was your idea behind adding the tag `itertools`?

Comment: Because i was thinking it's the right tool for things like that.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, more so since you accepted an answer that shows something different than what is shown in the question.

Comment: @fsimonjetz, Yeah, repeated keys are not necessary. So basically, this is what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in thinking of `itertools` but you want *permutations* and not *combinations*:

```
from itertools import permutations
lst = [{k: my_dict[k] for k in l} for l in permutations(my_dict)]

>>> lst
[{'location_01': 'Item_01', 'location_02': 'Item_02', 'location_03': 'Item_03'},
 {'location_01': 'Item_01', 'location_03': 'Item_03', 'location_02': 'Item_02'},
 {'location_02': 'Item_02', 'location_01': 'Item_01', 'location_03': 'Item_03'},
 {'location_02': 'Item_02', 'location_03': 'Item_03', 'location_01': 'Item_01'},
 {'location_03': 'Item_03', 'location_01': 'Item_01', 'location_02': 'Item_02'},
 {'location_03': 'Item_03', 'location_02': 'Item_02', 'location_01': 'Item_01'}]
```

### Edit:

If you instead want the permutations of all *values* so your resulting dictionaries are all different, use:

```
lst = [{k:v for k, v in zip(my_dict, vals)} for vals in permutations(my_dict.values())]

>>> lst
[{'location_01': 'Item_01', 'location_02': 'Item_02', 'location_03': 'Item_03'},
 {'location_01': 'Item_01', 'location_02': 'Item_03', 'location_03': 'Item_02'},
 {'location_01': 'Item_02', 'location_02': 'Item_01', 'location_03': 'Item_03'},
 {'location_01': 'Item_02', 'location_02': 'Item_03', 'location_03': 'Item_01'},
 {'location_01': 'Item_03', 'location_02': 'Item_01', 'location_03': 'Item_02'},
 {'location_01': 'Item_03', 'location_02': 'Item_02', 'location_03': 'Item_01'}]
```

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer, the output is different from what is shown in the question.

Comment: That's kind of redundant, the first and second (and 3rd and 4th, 5th and 6th) are essentially the same thing with a different order.

Comment: And since they are dictionaries, they *are* all the same.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - You're absolutely right. To have unique dictionaries, I should be taking the permutations on the dictionary *values*. Edited!

Answer (score 0):

Try `permutations`

```
import itertools
d={"location_01":"Item_01", "location_02":"Item_02", "location_03":"Item_03"}
x=[dict(zip(d, v)) for v in itertools.permutations(d.values(),3)]
for i in x:
    print(i)
```